# Getting better performance when searching for accounts

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm trying to find an efficient way to query large amounts of user accounts in ActiveDirectory, and I'm having a bit of an issue.

I have a script that goes through a file exported from another employee management program grabbing employeeIDs, which I then search for in ActiveDirectory. Every user account has an associated employeeID, and I use whether or not a certain ID is found in A/D to show whether an account should be created or deleted (if in file but not A/D, create; if in A/D but not file, delete). My problem is that I cannot find an efficient way to do this.

My old method was to search for every employeeID one at a time with Get-ADUser, but this was very slow. I've also tried pulling down all the non-system accounts, and then using Where-Object on the list to filter out the account that matches. This also gets very slow with large amounts of accounts because Where-Object is checking every single account in my array of accounts.

I think there must be a faster way to do this, since I'm able to slam a -contains on the attribute I'm trying to match and get a response for every ID within a minute or so, versus the 20 it takes to run a where-object. Any advice?

Some notes:

I have already preprocessed the IDs coming from the file and the IDs in ActiveDirectory to make sure there are no duplicates, so only getting the first result is fine.

Old Method (simplified with processing code taken out):

```
$csv = Import-CSV -Path $someFile
Foreach($line in $csv){
    $DoesAccountExist = Get-Aduser -filter {employeeID -eq $line.employeeID}
    }
```

Working in memory method:

```
$csv = Import-CSV -Path $someFile
$Users = Get-Aduser -filter *
$NonSystemUsers = $users | Where-Object {$_.employeeID -match $employeeIDPattern}

#This is the part that is slow
foreach($line in $csv){
    $DoesAccountExist = $NonSystemUsers | Where-Object {$_.employeeID -eq $line.employeeID}
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd start by doing one bulk query of AD, and building a hash table (Key = EmployeeID, Value = DN), and then work from that.

```
$hash = @{}

Get-ADUser -Properties EmployeeID -Filter * |
 foreach {$hash[$_.EmployeeID] = $_.DistinguishedName}

 $csv = Import-CSV -Path $someFile
 Foreach($line in $csv){
  $DoesAccountExist = [bool]($hash[$line.employeeid])
}
```

$hash[$line.employeeid] will return the DN of the user that belongs to that employeeid if it's in the table.

Comment: I might be misunderstanding, but are you saying the key should be the actual employeeID? And if so, what is DN = Value? Thanks!

Comment: Yes.  DN = DistinguishedName.  Left an example.

Comment: Sweet fancy lord in heaven, if I could give this points multiple times I would. That completely obliterated any problems with speed I had. Much appreciated!

Comment: +1, watch that the AD attribute `employeeID` is not required to be unique.

Comment: Thanks for the warning jscott. I did put in the qualifier that I am running pre-launch checks on my script to make sure there is no duplicates. I also strip out any duplicates I do find, so I should be safe in that regard.

Comment: @mjolinor: +1, This solution is neat! One query though. Is this method preferable if the directory size is over 200,000 user accounts?

Answer (score 3):

This script create a `HashTable` of users, and then simply compares the employeeID, from the CSV file, against the `HashTable`'s `Keys` property. This is **far** more efficient than calling `Where-Object` for each iteration.

```
$csv = Import-CSV -Path $someFile;
$Users = Get-Aduser -Filter *;
# Convert NonSystemUsers into a HashTable that can be indexed into
$NonSystemUsers = $users | Where-Object {$_.employeeID -match $employeeIDPattern} | % { @{ $_.employeeID = $_; } };

foreach($line in $csv){
    # Check if Dictionary keys contains the employee ID.
    # This is MUCH more efficient than calling Where-Object for each user
    $DoesAccountExist = $NonSystemUsers.Keys -contains $Line;
}
```

Comment: That will only reduce the size of my working set though, which I'm already doing on the Where-Object outside the foreach in the second example. My working set is already reduced to the size I need by the time I hit the foreach. The problem is that the set is still around 4000 accounts. What I need is a way to filter that set of accounts to the single account I need.

Comment: What criteria would you use to determine the specific account you need? Why do you need a dataset of 4,000 items, if you only need one? I'm a little confused.

Comment: I updated my answer with a solution. I think I understand your performance issue now. The recommendation I just made should help significantly, by using a `HashTable`.

Comment: Apologies for not being clear. I still need the data set of 4000 items because I need to run a comparison against the whole set for around 4000 other items. It seems like you already figured that out though, so I've upvoted your response as well. Mjolinor beat you to the response, so he got the answer, but the help is still appreciated!

Comment: Ah, I missed his response, otherwise I would have simply rescinded mine. Looks like he did have it first. Upvoted his also.

Answer (score 0):

The quickest method you have here is to join the two objects $csv and $users based upon the employeeID field present in both.  I have my own function named JoinObjects, which I cannot share unless I wish to get in trouble.  However, the blog post below has an example that is nearly like my own.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2012/07/13/join-object.aspx